# cpuminer json rpc call failed

Tags: bitcoind, litecoin, cpu

```
root@i-M116V:/var/www/cpuminer-2.2.3# ./minerd
[2013-12-27 15:22:35] 2 miner threads started, using 'scrypt' algorithm.
[2013-12-27 15:22:35] Binding thread 1 to cpu 1
[2013-12-27 15:22:35] Binding thread 0 to cpu 0
[2013-12-27 15:22:35] HTTP request failed: Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:9332; Connection refused
[2013-12-27 15:22:35] json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds
```

I'm using a laptop with no GPU.

```
root@i-M116V:~# netstat -anp | grep 9332
root@i-M116V:~# 

i@i-M116V:~$ cd /home/i/デスクトップ/cpuminer-master/cpuminer
i@i-M116V:~/デスクトップ/cpuminer-master/cpuminer$ ./minerd -o ltc.give-me-coins.com:3333 -u sukarutinohu.1 -p 1
```

Comment: This question is missing the part where you specify your question.

Answer (score 2):

You should sign up for a pool service and configure minerd to send shares to that service.  Right now it is attempting to connect to a local instance of a scrypt coin (litecoind I would presume) on port 9332 for solo mining.  If that is what you intended then verify that you have a server running and listening on that port.  It is also not recommended to run minerd as root in case theres is a remote buffer overflow vulnerability in the application.  You can check by executing the following command:

```
netstat -anp | grep 9332
```

This will tell you what application had that port open if any does.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the cryptocurrency's daemon (for bitcoin it is the bitcoind, for example) as a server and configure it to accept your IP address if it is hosted on another machine, via the rpcallowip=192.168.1.x command. The 9332 port is that daemon's RPC server to which your miner tries to connect and fails.